Reseting an array results in undefined
I'm trying to create a "killfeed" script which is supposed to show "kills" in a feed with randomized names from an array.
I don't want the same name to appear twice in the same feed, so I want to remove every name as it is picked from the array, but I also want to be able to reset the array with the original names.
I've figured out the mostpart, but I'm having issues with the reset part as after the "reset" I'm left with an "undefined" response.


const myNames = ["Niko", "Anomaly", "Kandis"];
let names = [...myNames];

function getRandomName() {
  if (names.length === 0) {
    resetNames();
  }
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
  let randomName = names[randomIndex];
  names.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  return randomName;
}

function addKill() {
  kills = $("li").length + 1;
  let selectedName = getRandomName();
  $("#killfeed").append('<li><b class="ct">ne0lines</b> killed <i class="t">' + selectedName + '</i></li>');
}

function resetNames() {
  let names = [...myNames];
}

function resetKill() {
  $("ul").fadeOut(1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("li").remove();
  }, 1000);
  $("ul").fadeIn();
  resetNames();
}
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: rajdhani, sans-serif !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px #b50000 solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: -100%;
  animation: smooth-appear 1s ease forwards;
}

b {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

.ct {
  color: rgb(105, 180, 255);
}

.t {
  color: rgb(237, 208, 87);
}

@keyframes smooth-appear {
  to {
    right: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="javascript:addKill();">Add kill</button>
<button onClick="javascript:resetKill();">Reset</button>
<ul id="killfeed"></ul>




the smallest fix would be to remove the let from your resetNames() function
names = [...myNames];

The fix is simple. You just need to remove let before let names = ... in your resetNames() function.
This is because you already have a variable called names in the global scope, so you can just re-assign a value to this global variable. What you are currently doing is creating a new second variable also named names which shadows (yes, that is the proper technical term for it) your global variable. These two variables are completely different variables which just happen to have the same name. To get a better understanding of why that is you need to understand scoping in JavaScript and how it works. Essentially JavaScript will always try to resolve a variable starting from the inner-most scope and if the variable is not found there move on to outer scopes until the variable is eventually found in the global scope, or will return undefined if it is also not found there.
Please see also:

MDN Docs - Scope
Variable Shadowing in JavaScript

Here the code with the simple change applied and the reset problem fixed.


const myNames = ["Niko", "Anomaly", "Kandis"];
let names = [...myNames];

function getRandomName() {
  if (names.length === 0) {
    resetNames();
  }
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
  let randomName = names[randomIndex];
  names.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  return randomName;
}

function addKill() {
  kills = $("li").length + 1;
  let selectedName = getRandomName();
  $("#killfeed").append('<li><b class="ct">ne0lines</b> killed <i class="t">' + selectedName + '</i></li>');
}

function resetNames() {
  // use "names" from outer scope (global scope here) instead of declaring a new variable "names" which shadows the global one
  names = [...myNames];
}

function resetKill() {
  $("ul").fadeOut(1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("li").remove();
  }, 1000);
  $("ul").fadeIn();
  resetNames();
}
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: rajdhani, sans-serif !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px #b50000 solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: -100%;
  animation: smooth-appear 1s ease forwards;
}

b {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

.ct {
  color: rgb(105, 180, 255);
}

.t {
  color: rgb(237, 208, 87);
}

@keyframes smooth-appear {
  to {
    right: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="javascript:addKill();">Add kill</button>
<button onClick="javascript:resetKill();">Reset</button>
<ul id="killfeed"></ul>




FYI: Scoping and variable shadowing is present in pretty much all common programming languages, so it certainly worth getting aquainted with.


That was an easy fix! Thank you! And thank you for explaining the issue aswell!
